# transferring bytes of data continous using SPI

Tags: spi

I am pretty new to SPI module. I need to write bytes of data at 3 different locations of the temperature sensor memory only one time after power up. My doubts is, can i write all data by asserting CS(slave select) pin only one time. Or, do i need to write first data by asserting the CS pin, then deassert CS pin, Write 2nd data by asserting CS, then deassert CS, Write 3rd data by asserting CS pin and then deasserting CS pin. Also, if this the case, do i need to give delay between first, second and third write data.
Please reply

Comment: **All** that information is in the datasheet. You need to either delay or poll a bit to determine if the EEPROM is ready for the next write.

Comment: datasheet mentions only the write sequence and the write sequence.Sorry its temperature sensor register location

Comment: If there is truly nothing that covers this, and you only need to do it once on startup, what exactly is the problem with doing a unique /CS cycle for each byte?  Without the identity of the part (and preferably a link to the data sheet) this is on the border of being an insufficiently stated question to survive on this site.

Answer (score 2):

You have to look to the datasheet for the official answer, but as a general rule SPI devices treat a CS# negation as a "communications done" indication. This means that as a general rule, if you set CS# high you are telling the device "I'm done talking to you". There are exceptions to this, but that's what the datasheet is for.

Also, generally speaking, when you are writing data to a SPI device you need a way of telling the SPI device WHERE you want this data to go. (e.g. is it going to address 0x123 or address 0x456? Are you writing to a status register, a data register or a control register?)

Take, for example, the [AT250x0A SPI EEPROM](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc3348.pdf). When you access it you don't just "write data" to it. You must send at an "instruction" which tells it what you want it to do (read data from the chip, write data to the chip, erase the chip, return an ID code, etc.). If you want it to read or write from its memory array you're sending at least two bytes: the instruction and the address you want to access.

When you're done talking to the device, you negate the CS# line. ALL devices have some finite time you must wait before asserting CS# again. This is the "CS# high time" or "Tcs" parameter for the AT250x0A datasheet. Your particular device will have a similar spec you should follow if you want reliable communications.

You should perhaps check out a few [SPI](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-peripheral-interface-spi) [tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SPIEEPROM) [pages](http://www.corelis.com/education/SPI_Tutorial.htm) to help demystify the protocol. It's not rocket science but if you get off on the wrong foot it can take a while to untangle yourself.

Comment: yes spi will be sending data to the different register location 3 times. I need to look into datasheet for minimum CS high time before sending next data to the different register location.

Comment: it will be VERY unusual if you are violating the high CS time, but yes, you need to adhere to the specs. :-)